# How to use the current property value for valueFrom in ObjectAnimator's xml?

Tags: android, android-animation

```
<objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="cardBackgroundColor"
                android:valueFrom="????"
                android:valueTo="@color/defaultCardColor"
                android:valueType="colorType" />
```

I want to use the current value of the `cardBackgroundColor` in the `valueFrom` field. Is this possible in only XML?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone strays on this question: just omit the `android:valueFrom` attribute in animator XML and current value will be used.